# Does Marvel have an equivalent of the Green Lantern?

Tags: marvel, dc, green-lantern

Does Marvel have an equivalent of the Green Lantern?

I know there's "Nova", but I mean is there a superhero or villain in Marvel that has the same powers as — or "close to" that of — the Green Lantern?

For example:

- a ring
- some kind of powers that look like a light show
- can make constructs similar to a Lantern Corp-er

Comment: Not sure if any of these will exactly match your criteria, but [this site](https://www.superherodb.com/energy-constructs/60-161/) has a long list of characters from all comic that can make energy constructs.

Comment: Is a literal ring necessary?  Because Star Brand (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Brand) comes pretty darn close.

Comment: @mweiss — I'd say Star Brand counts, if [DC's response](http://thatsmyskull.blogspot.com/2005/08/jim-shooter-vs-green-lantern.html) is anything to go by.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Freedom Ring

> Freedom Ring (real name Curtis Doyle) is a fictional superhero appearing in American comic books published by Marvel Comics. The character was created by writer Robert Kirkman. Curtis first appeared in Marvel Team-Up vol. 3 #20 (July 2006), becoming Freedom Ring in the next issue. He appeared across the series' storyline "Freedom Ring" for five issues. The character is depicted as a normal civilian who comes across a ring that grants him the ability to alter reality.
>
> [...]
>
> Curtis Doyle originally had no inherent super-powers on his own. However, the character comes into possession of a ring crafted from a fragment of a destroyed Cosmic Cube which allows the wearer to alter reality within a radius of roughly 15 feet (4.6m) around him, giving him a 30-foot (9.1 m) sphere of reality he can alter.
>
> After his first attempt as Freedom Ring, he altered his physiology to give himself superhuman strength, speed, stamina and durability.
>
> [image: Freedom Ring, in costume]
>
> Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_Ring)

The [Cosmic Ring](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Cosmic_Ring) gives Curtis Doyle the powers of flight, super-strength, increased durability, the ability to generate objects, and a way to overcome the paralysis of his legs.  Generated objects first manifest in a shimmer of light and then take on a normal appearance:

[image: Comic book page.]
— [Image source](https://not-unwise.livejournal.com/329408.html)

Comment: Does anyone else find it odd that Wikipedia feels the need to qualify him as a "fictional" superhero?

Comment: @CobaltZorch that's probably because of [these people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-life_superhero) .

Comment: @CobaltZorch I find it odd that they described something as a "30 foot sphere". In full context its obvious they meant a sphere with a diameter of 30 feet, but the phrase by itself is meaningless.

Comment: @CobaltZorch: Not odd at all; an encyclopedia shouldn't blithely describe something non-real as if it were real, even if most native-English-speaking adult readers would recognize that it couldn't possibly be real. (And anyway, "fictional" is more specific than merely "not real"; consider e.g. [ether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether_(classical_element)), which is neither real nor fictional.)

Comment: The **real** Reality Distortion Field :-)

Comment: @mikołak - Actually, no. Its because of [these people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_(comics)).   Read the comic if you get a chance. I'm not even joking a little.

Comment: @CobaltZorch It's actually from a decision made fairly early on in Wikipedia's history. People would write about fictional characters from an in-universe point of view, and it would often come off as if they were real. Consensus was that this was a bad thing, so a [guideline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS:REALWORLD) was created that, among many things, said that you should only write from a real-world perspective, and clearly identify that which is fictional. One of the easiest ways to do this was to explicitly say the character is fictional.

Answer (score 38):

The first Marvel pendant to Green lantern was **[Doctor Spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Spectrum#Joseph_Ledger_(Earth-712))**.

Doctor Spectrum was originally introduced in 1969 a member of the Squadron Sinister, an evil pastiche of Justice League, where he was the stand-in for Green Lantern. Later, in 1971, Marvel invented a parallel Earth reminescent of the DC Universe, with a good version of the Squadron, now called [Squadron Supreme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Spectrum#Joseph_Ledger_(Earth-712)), in the role of the Justice League (and a good Doctor Spectrum filling in for GT).

Later still, in 2004, the Squadron Supreme was rebooted with J. Michael Straczynski at the helm in the title *Supreme Power* and spin-offs, featuring yet another version of Doctor Spectrum.

There was also a female version at one point, introduced in 2005 in *The Thunderbolts*.

All versions of Doctor Spectrum derive their abilities from an alien gem called the Power Prism, worn on the back of the hand. It bestows on a host the ability to project and manipulate light energy in various colors; create light energy constructs of various shapes, sizes and colors; flight; protection from the rigors of space and the ability to become intangible. The Power Prism is vulnerable to ultra-violet light.

[This article](https://alchetron.com/Doctor-Spectrum) has information about these versions (and more) of Doctor Spectrum.

[image: The original evil Doctor Spectrum]
The original evil Doctor Spectrum

[image]
Squadron Supreme version

[image]
Supreme Power version

[image]
Female Doctor Spectrum

Comment: +1 Doctor Spectrum is the first green lantern copy.

Answer (score 17):

A few characters named Quasar wear the [Quantum Bands](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Quantum_Bands), a piece of superscience jewelry that lets one create light constructs through its control of electro-magnetic radiation, although said constructs can be completely invisible. These bands have been gifted by Eon to multiple heroes. The manifestation of these light constructs often seems to consist of invisible armor across their bodies or spheres of light around their hands with which they pummel opponents. They can construct more complex items, but they can also blast the same energy out, removing the need to create a more complex construct.

[image: Phyla Vell holding an energy sword] [image: Quasar constructs a re-entry shell] [image: Quasar blasts energy]

Comment: Nova's power comes from the Nova force. The quantum bands are usually associated with Quasar (all your pictures depict iterations of Quasar, not Nova(s))